# Use Array.forEach to call an "instance" method

Tags: javascript

If I have an array of objects like:

```
function Fruit() {
    this.onTree = true;
}
Fruit.prototype.pick = function() {
    this.onTree = false;
};

var arr = [new Fruit(), new Fruit()];
```

Is there any way to use Array.forEach to call the `pick` method on each one without creating an extra anonymous function?

```
arr.forEach(function(f) { f.pick(); });
```

I thought maybe I could do something with `Fruit.prototype.pick.call` but then the `this` context of the `call` function is lost so I have to `bind` that and I end up with:

```
arr.forEach(Function.call.bind(Fruit.prototype.pick));
```

which works but it's pretty ugly. Basically I just want something like this from Java:

```
arr.forEach(Fruit::pick);
```

Comment: Does it have to be a call to `.forEach()`, or would `for (let f of arr) f.pick();` do? (Assuming ES6 is OK, which I realise it might not be.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use many approaches, but at least you need to pass a function to `forEach` because that is it's syntax. But if you use `ES6`, you can work with `arrow functions` and it can be more beautiful.

```
arr.forEach(f => f.pick());
```

Comment: this is not javascript.

Comment: @gcv and what is this?

Comment: ES6 :) or ECMAScript 2015 if you rather.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I guess I should have specified what version of Javascript I want to target. I'm not sure that has wide enough support for me to use at the moment.

Comment: @gcb So... JavaScript?

Comment: I'll accept this since I kind of doubt there's something shorter for older versions. Thought it wouldn't hurt to ask though

Comment: well, he is already on ES5 anyway, and I was adding the correct tag when you suggested ES6 features. Yes, it is a superset of the language, but good luck dismissing that as minor when your ecosystem depends on one or another, such as writing for browsers which is 90% of what this is about.

Comment: @gcb Most of said ecosystem uses Babel, TypeScript or some other transpiler now.

Answer (score 1):

You missed `()` after Fruit definition, didn't you?

```
    function Fruit() {
        this.onTree = true;
    }
    Fruit.prototype.pick = function() {
        this.onTree = false;
    };

    var arr = [new Fruit(), new Fruit()];

    arr.forEach(function(val, index) {
        val.pick();
        console.log(val);
    })
```

I tested that one nd it change those fruit.onTree into false.

Comment: Yeah I typed it directly into stackoverflow so I made a typo. Fixed now

Comment: Does it runs now?

Comment: Yes, the original question missed the `()`, but that isn't the issue. OP asked how to use `.forEach()` *without* the anonymous function wrapping the call to `f.pick()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use ES6 (but, well, it's 2017...) you can store your `this` reference

```
 var self = this;

function invoker(item){
    Item.pick.call(self);
}

 array.forEach(invoker)
```

Or just use a `for` loop

Comment: Where would the `self` variable be that it could work with all of the array items in turn? In any case you've just replaced the anonymous wrapper with a named wrapper, so it could've just said `item.pick()`...

Comment: I thought it was a matter of beauty. This is way more readable in my opinion

Comment: Readable isn't helpful when the code doesn't work. Why are you using `.call()`? What is `this`? Your code changes the result. If you think a named function is more readable then fine, but it should still just have `item.pick()`...

Comment: When you use `call` the first argument is the context of `this`. Passing a stored self will make the *internal* call use the *external* `this`. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: (I'm assuming that the `pick` function is intended to access the `this` of the function wrapping the `forEach`. Did I get the question wrong?)

Comment: The original code in the question is calling the `.pick()` method on the individual objects in the array, so the result of the loop is that each object in the array has its `.onTree` property updated.